# Golang UDP Multicast

Tags: go, multicast

Im doing some testing for receiving multicast UDP stream and save it to file using the below functions:

```
func Record2(udp string, filePath string) {
    c1, err := net.ListenPacket("udp4", udp)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    defer c1.Close()
    p1 := ipv4.NewPacketConn(c1)
    en0, err := net.InterfaceByName("enp3s0")
    addr, _ := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp4", udp)
    if err := p1.JoinGroup(en0, addr); err != nil {

    }
    Bee.DelFile(filePath)
    fo, err := os.Create(filePath)
    defer fo.Close()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    io.Copy(fo, p1)

}
func Record(udp string, filePath string) {
    addr, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp4", udp)

    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    Bee.DelFile(filePath)
    fo, err := os.Create(filePath)
    defer fo.Close()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    l, err := net.ListenMulticastUDP("udp4", nil, addr)

    defer l.Close()
    l.SetReadBuffer(maxDatagramSize)
    io.Copy(fo, l)

}
 go Record2("224.1.2.2:1234", "file1")
 go Record2("224.1.2.1:1234", "file2")
 go Record("224.1.2.2:1234", "file3")
 Record("224.1.2.1:1234", "file4")
```

the problem is that udp stream have different content while all files saved got the same content of the first address

this is not occuring when using UDP addresses with different ports

im not sure if this is related to SO_REUSEADDR

how to fix that?

Comment: Have you read up on what behaviour is enabled by using `SO_REUSRADDR`? Why did you use it in the first place? I'm asking because your question basically sounds like this: "I have a problem X due to Y (if I disable Y the problem did not occur); should I not use Y?". This begs an obvious answer and hence begs the question about why do you have Y in the first place.

Comment: i didnt say i enabled/disabled SO_REUSRADDR, i said it might be related to it as the code is working perfectly when using different ports (based on my knowledge in c++)

how to enabled/disable SO_REUSRADDR in golang anyways?

Comment: when using netstat -tulnp, the system is showing 0 0.0.0.0:1234, usually it should be 224.1.2.2:1234